# Checkout with Multiple Addresses and Onepage

Tags: magento2, checkout

Checkout with Multiple Addresses and Onepage. Both save at `sales_order` table in database. But I don't know what function it call to save at `sales_order` table. Who can help me?

This is my di.xml

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Multishipping\Model\Checkout\Type\Multishipping">
        <plugin name="logging-checkout-multi" type="TTV\OrderLog\Plugin\Log" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="logging-checkout" type="TTV\OrderLog\Plugin\Log" sortOrder="2"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

function in TTV\OrderLog\Plugin|Log

```
    public function beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder()
    {
        $this->_log->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('var/log/information.log'));
        $productList = $this->_sessionCheckout->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($productList as $product) {
            $productName = $product->getName();
            $productQty = $product->getQty();
            $productPrice = $product->getPrice();
            $this->_log->info("Product Name: " . $productName . " - " . "Product Quantity: " . $productQty . " - " . "Product Price: " . $productPrice);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your Plugin was wrong:http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Answer (score 1):

1) For the multishipping:

*vendor/magento/module-multishipping/Controller/Checkout/OverviewPost.php*

```
 public function execute()
{
    ......
    $this->_getCheckout()->createOrders();
    ......
}
```

2) For the onepage checkout, Magento uses API: `/V1/carts/mine/payment-information`

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php*

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
    ) {
        $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
        return $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
}
```

Comment: i know but i think it call at 1 function (exam call API). Because i want create a plugin for both

Comment: Which is your purpose, you can explain more. I think we can use Observer.

Comment: i must use plugin. And if follow your answer. I will create two plugin. But i just want create one. Please help me.

Comment: You can explain more, I think I can give you the solution. But, I need to know more about your purpose. Please update your question with more details.

Comment: this function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder <- it call at Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement ????

Comment: Yes, it is. Ah! You can use Plugin `savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder ` for both cases: One page and multi.

Comment: if i use savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder just beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder can use. And onepage is not working for me.

Comment: i have already updated di.xml file.

Comment: You can update the question with your `beforeSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder` plugin?

Comment: ok. i updated this. I just want create log file to save product of each order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51570/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-nguyen-cong-binh).